# Silverstripe Class GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor

Tags: grid, silverstripe

How does teh Class GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor in SIlverstripe work with data relations. Why do one need it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work with data relations directly. It's just a shortcut for configuring your gridfield for managing and editing relations of your gridfield. [A quick look at the code might shed some light on it](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor.html#235-256). The config items it adds are pretty self explanatory. You might also [consult the API Docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor.html) for another explantion what this class does for you.

Understanding how the gridfield works is a bit hard in the beginning, but it's very modular and powerful. Out of the box it does pretty nothing but you can do a lot with it when you know how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You use the GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor to configure your GridFields. The default configuration for a GridField is using a GridField_RecordEditor configuration... which means, by default you only have the option to edit existing data object (DOs displayed in the GridField). If you switch to the GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor configuration, you'll be able to link already existing data objects to the GridField, or unlink linked DOs in the GridField.